# Convert .png images into a .ppt presentation on Linux?

Tags: linux, microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow, presentations

I've created a presentation as a series of .png images, one per slide.   What is a good way to convert these into a .ppt (PowerPoint) that I can give to some audio-visual person?  I'm entirely on Linux, with no Windows or Mac software available.

(Or maybe PowerPoint isn't the only game in town for presentation file formats?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd output to PDF, which is commonly used for presentations. To convert use the `convert` program (from Image Magick).

```
convert *.png presentation.pdf
```

If you don't have convert yet, install the `imagemagick` package

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

(It looks like you can also use convert directly to a .ppt file, but for me this doesn't work as well.)

Comment: Looks good and easy.  Will try that.   I wonder if ImageMagick can go the opposite way - make .png or .jpg from a given .pdf?

Comment: I use pdfimages for that. It extracts all the embedded images from a pdf (part of xpdf-utils package).

Answer (score 4):

You can use OpenOffice.org Impress to import each of these PNGs into single slide, apply the desired transitions and export to a `.ppt` file.

[OpenOffice.org](http://download.openoffice.org/) comes with most Linux distros

Comment: Well, that seems obvious!    Will try that.   I did try OO a while ago, but thinking only of using Impress to create the content.  I found it lacking in graphics capability.

Comment: This has the disadvantage of having to manually deal with each image. Is there a way to handle say 50 images at once?

Comment: I'm not sure. Have a look at @Dennis' answer http://superuser.com/questions/132767/convert-png-images-into-a-ppt-presentation-on-linux/132957#132957

Comment: I would recommend that people use LibreOffice nowadays instead of OpenOffice. LibreOffice is the maintained fork of OpenOffice.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to directly convert the PNG files to a PDF or other format presentation,  create a new presentation in Inkscape with the PNGs imported.  Inkscape with Inkscape Slides turns out to be a great way to make presentations, and a good way to deal with old presentations that exist only as PNGs.  (See question [Converting Inkscape layers directly to a slideshow presentation?](https://superuser.com/questions/132771/converting-inkscape-layers-directly-to-a-slideshow-presentation))

However, the other answer recommending ImageMagick convert is useful too.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Markdown file with all the slides, and then use [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) to convert it to a PowerPoint file. Here's example Markdown:

```
![](image1.png)

---

![](image2.png)

---

![](image3.png)
```

And here's the command to convert it to a PowerPoint file:

```
pandoc slides.md -o slides.pptx
```

Answer (score 0):

Good news! There's a way to do this using **LibreOffice Impress**!

Open a new slideshow with LibreOffice Impress, then click Insert, Media, Photo Album. This dialog will appear:

[image: Dialog]

Click "Add" to add the photos you want to add, and then click "Insert Slides" when you are doing. LibreOffice will create a slide for each image. Save it as "filename.pptx" (PowerPoint's format) when you are done, if you need a PowerPoint file.

I recommend LibreOffice over OpenOffice by the way, as the former is much better maintained than the latter.

Answer (score -1):

I don't remember if this is the exact solution I used, but I have run some kind of add-on to OpenOffice that just took a whole directory full of images and created individual slides from them. It was absolute magic. Give this a try, I hope it's the one I'm thinking of http://ooomacros.org/user.php#95976

Comment: The link is broken