# Converting Inkscape layers directly to a slideshow presentation?

Tags: linux, presentations, inkscape

I'm creating a slideshow in Inkscape.  There's one or more layer per slide, plus several background layers, and some special layers to be used on several slides in a row, etc.

In the past, I'd create each slide as a .png image by turning on appropriate layers and exporting an image.  This is tedious and easy to make mistakes.

Is it possible to automate this?  To enable the right layers and save all slides directly to a file format suitable for presenatations, such as .ppt, which I can give to anyone for display?

The solution will have to work on Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Inkscape slide](http://projects.abourget.net/inkscapeslide/) does pretty much what you are looking for: given a set of layers it will create a pdf from them (I would say that's even better than ppt output). How different output pages are composed can be freely configured via a configuration layer. It needs [pypdf](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyPdf) installed.

And with [TeXText](http://www.elisanet.fi/ptvirtan/software/textext/) you can even include LaTeX text or figures. Profit!

Comment: Interesting!  Just grabbed a copy - it's just one file with python code.  It works!  

LaTeX will be useful too, though I'm not quite at that point of needing it.

Comment: I have made my presentation using Inkscape Slide, and am quite happy with the result.