# How: Convert Image Files from Screenshots of a Presentation to PPT - on Windows?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, screenshot

I've got a bunch of screenshots from some lengthy online presentations and do wish to pull some structured notes from them AS IS into PPT/X.

A manual copy or type would take a lot of time.

The presenter used a standard B&W so there's not much in terms of distracting design.

Would prefer to replicate these screenshots as slides into PPT.

I presume it would require some kind of OCR of the images and some level of PPT layout/ structure/ bullets understanding by whatever way or steps its done.

Similar but how to commonly do it on windows?
[Convert .png images into a .ppt presentation on Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/132767/convert-png-images-into-a-ppt-presentation-on-linux)

Comment: Both of the Linux solutions will work on Windows ...

Comment: @DavidPostill - I'd like the "text" "as is" in the original  bullet/ outline format in the PPT/X -  so that I can make notes from it. i.e. OCR & Disintegration/ Segregation of outline of text & bullets from source image & background

He seems to just want present SLIDES whether they are "disintgrateable" or not. PS: Which 2 solutions, because their objective is visual presenting, mine is having the source structure & separation recreated from a reductive lossy format such as an Image.

Comment: @DavidPostill - To that end even non image PDFs do have some Text data in their digital structure, images largely FLATTENED